# How do I find transconductance gm in this exercise?

Tags: amplifier, bjt, differential

We have the following exercise :

[image]

I have questions regarding a) and b)

For a) the solution is [image]

As for b) you can kinda see it in the above solution that IE=0.5 mA ,I think that this is because IE=I/2 =1/2 =0.5 mA  .In the solution it is also written gm=0.5/25 where 25 is Vt. I dont understand why is gm=IE/Vt in this case when gm is always gm=IC/Vt?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that gm = IC/vt.  But also remember IE = IB + IC.  If beta is high, IB is very small so IE ~ IC.  It's just an approximation.

Answer (score 0):

For scetching the differential half circuit and for finding the diff. gain you must not forget that each BJT stage has negative feedback because the emitters are **not** at signal ground. Exception: Push-pull differential input signal with Vin+=-Vin-.

So - what is the "overall diff. gain"?

If one of the inputs is grounded, the other BJT is a common emitter configuration with a feedback resistance identical to the input resistance of the other stage (in common-base configuration) **re=1/gm** (neglecting the very large current source resistance, gm=transconductance).

Hence, between the base node and the collector node of one transistor the gain is

**A,diff=gm*Rc/(1+gm/gm)=gmRc/2**

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is correct, because when the current flows throught emmiter to base and collecter region due to large area of the collector, it will contribute more toward the current as opposed to base region (so, i.e IE~IC) in such a way it transfers from emmiter to collector.